# developing for new instruction sets

Tags: x86, sse, avx

Intel is set to release a new instruction set called [AVX](http://software.intel.com/sites/avx/), which includes an extension of SSE to 256-bit operation.  That is, either 4 double-precision elements or 8 single-precision elements.

How would one go about developing code for AVX, considering there's no hardware out there that supports it yet?  More generally, how can developers write code for hardware that doesn't exist, for instance if they want to have software ready when the supporting CPU is released?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something about your question but it seems the answer is on the website that you linked.  Use the Intel Compiler to get access to the new intrinsic functions so you can generate the code and use the emulator to test it.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=intel+avx+emulator found http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-software-development-emulator/ pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

Contact Intel and ask if they have a simulator available? Not a hardware level simulator, but an instruction set simulator. Indeed Intel have an emulator available.

Or you could write one yourself - might be a fun project for some people!

Comment: Intel SDE (Software Development Emulator) is  - http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-software-development-emulator/ It uses PIN dynamic instruction translator to emulate newer instructions. Current version "includes support for SSE4, AES and PCLMULQDQ and the Intel® AVX"