# Which assemblers currently support the AVX instruction set?

Tags: x86, assembly, simd, avx

I'd like to start and play with some AVX (advanced vector extension) instructions. I know Intel provides an emulator to test software containing these instructions (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458869/developing-for-new-instruction-sets)), but since I don't want to manually write hex code, the question arises as to **which assemblers currently know the AVX instruction set?**

I would be most interested in assemblers that run under Windows and can be made to accept Intel syntax.

Comment: Is there any emulator for AVX?  There's no hardware out that supports it yet.

Comment: @Nathan Fellman - yes, there's an emulator. Have a look at http://software.intel.com/en-us/avx/ under download -> Intel Software Development Emulator. So far, it seems to work fine for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MASM 64Bits (ML64.EXE) seems to support AVX instruction set.

From MS [vcblog](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/11/02/visual-c-code-generation-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx), it is said:

> **Support for AVX in Intel and AMD
> processors:**   Intel AVX (Intel
> Advanced Vector Extensions) is a 256
> bit instruction set extension to SSE
> and is designed for applications that
> are floating point intensive [...].
>
> In
> VS2010 release, all AVX features and
> instructions are fully supported via
> intrinsic and /arch:AVX.  Many
> optimizations have been added to
> improve the code quality of AVX code
> generation which will be described
> with more details in an upcoming blog
> post. In addition to AVX support in
> the compiler, the Microsoft Macro
> Assembler (MASM) in VS2010 also
> supports the Intel AVX instruction set
> for x86 and x64.

EDIT:

YASM and NASM seems to support Intel AVX too, according this page:
http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-software-development-emulator/

Comment: What version would that be? (My - admittedly old - copy doesn't seem to.)

Comment: I believe it's the masm version that ships with Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2. Keep in mind that there are still no AVX capable CPU out there..

Comment: Great! (I did mention the emulator exactly because there are no AVX capable CPUs yet.)

Comment: @PhiS You might also like €ASM https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/#ShortCharacteristic

Answer (score 7):

Besides masm, recent yasm and gas do support avx too, and so does the inline assembler of gcc.