# Intel AVX2 Assembly Development

Tags: assembly, intel, avx2

I am Optimizing the my Video Decoder using Intel assembly for 64-bit architecture. For optimization am using AVX2 instruction set.

My development Environment:-
OS :- Win 7(64-bit)
IDE:- MSVS 2008(Prof)
CPU:- Core i5(support up to AVX)
Assembler:- YASM

I would like to know is there any emulators to run and debug my AVX2 code without upgrading the hardware.
Majorly am looking to run & debug my application on existing environment.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [developing for new instruction sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458869/developing-for-new-instruction-sets)

Answer (score 6):

You can download the [Intel SDE (Software Development Emulator)](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-software-development-emulator/) for free and use that - it works pretty well. Native instructions run at full speed - only your AVX2 instructions will be emulated.

You'll need a compiler that supports AVX2 as well of course (gcc, clang, Intel ICC or failing that an up-to-date Visual Studio).

One final word: I would strongly advise that you use intrinsics rather than native asm - it will save a you a lot of time and effort, it will be more portable, and it makes things easier if you need to target both 32 bit and 64 bit platforms.